# 2 case statements which are linked

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am relatively new in SQL coding and have a question regarding case statements.

What I want to achieve: I want to create a query being used for calculating correct obsolescence provision.

For this I need to create a column called `Inventory Reach` and one called `Devaluation Class`. Both fields will be calculated.

The outcome in the field devaluation class is depending on the inventory reach calculation. I.e. depending on the inventory reach the devaluation class will be determined. E.g. if `inventory reach` is bigger than 9 , the devaluation class is 1 (100%). When executing the code below I get the following error message:

> Invalid column name 'Inventory Reach'.

So for me it seems to be so that the 2nd case statement fails and it hangs together with the first case statement. But I struggle to find an answer what is wrong. I would appreciate if someone could bring some light into the dark.

Thank you in advance

```
Select 
    [Material]
    ,[Plnt]
    ,case
        when [calculate 5-year demand] = 0
            then 9.01
        when  [BAAS SO GI (601) 36] = 0
            then 9.01
        when [MS] <> 'BI' or [MS] <> 'BO' 
            then ([Stock all SP WH]/([calculate 5-year demand]/5))
        when [MS] = 'BO'
            then ([Stock all SP WH]/[BAAS SO GI (601) 36])
        when [MS] ='BI'
            then 0
        else 9.01
    end as [Inventory Reach]
    ,case
        when [Inventory Reach] > 9
            then 1
        else 0.9
    end as [Devaluation Class]
from [BAAS_PowerBI].[dbo].[Obs]
```

Comment: Case _expressions_, not statements.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access to the aliases in the select clause in the same select clause. There is a simple fix and that is using a derived table or a common table expression:

```
;with cte as
(
    Select 
        [Material]
        ,[Plnt]
        ,case
            when [calculate 5-year demand] = 0
                then 9.01
            when  [BAAS SO GI (601) 36] = 0
                then 9.01
            when [MS] <> 'BI' or [MS] <> 'BO' 
                then ([Stock all SP WH]/([calculate 5-year demand]/5))
            when [MS] = 'BO'
                then ([Stock all SP WH]/[BAAS SO GI (601) 36])
            when [MS] ='BI'
                then 0
            else 9.01
        end as [Inventory Reach]
    from [BAAS_PowerBI].[dbo].[Obs]
)

select [Material]
        ,[Plnt]
        ,[Inventory Reach]
        ,case
            when [Inventory Reach] > 9
                then 1
            else 0.9
        end as [Devaluation Class]
from cte
```

The above code is using a common table expression which is (in this schenario) basically the same as using a derived table, only more readable. Here's the derived table equivalent:

```
select [Material]
        ,[Plnt]
        ,[Inventory Reach]
        ,case
            when [Inventory Reach] > 9
                then 1
            else 0.9
        end as [Devaluation Class]
from 
(
    Select 
        [Material]
        ,[Plnt]
        ,case
            when [calculate 5-year demand] = 0
                then 9.01
            when  [BAAS SO GI (601) 36] = 0
                then 9.01
            when [MS] <> 'BI' or [MS] <> 'BO' 
                then ([Stock all SP WH]/([calculate 5-year demand]/5))
            when [MS] = 'BO'
                then ([Stock all SP WH]/[BAAS SO GI (601) 36])
            when [MS] ='BI'
                then 0
            else 9.01
        end as [Inventory Reach]
    from [BAAS_PowerBI].[dbo].[Obs]
) derived
```

Comment: Hello Zohar, thank your very much for your input.It is much appreciated:-) I wasn´t aware of that an alias is not accessible in the same select clause. Your solution looks good. There is one thing I would need to change. I would like to have the inventory reach visible in the separate column. This might of importance in the output table, e.g. for filtering/analysis purposes. How can I manage this? What needs to be changed in your query in order to see the inventory reach in a separate column in addition to the devaluation class column? Thank you in advance

Comment: Then simply add it to the query (edited my answer to reflect that in both options).

Comment: thanks, that was easy:-) Last but not least I would need to calculate the obsolescence value per material. The formula is: [MAP]*[Overstock QTY]*[Devaluation Class]. As you can see that it is dependent on the alias [Devaluation Class] which we have calculated  in the formula above. In order to avoid the same trouble with an alias in a select clause as in my original query do I have to create an additional CTE for that? Or how can I integrate the formula above. The field [MAP] and [Overstock QTY] do already exist in the table [BAAS_PowerBI].[dbo].[Obs]. Your help is much appreciated:-)

Comment: Yes, you will either need to add another cte or another cross apply (like in Gordon's answer).

Comment: Hi Zoran, the CTE solution is working now as it should be. Many thanks for your support. In order to improve the clarity I would like to round some fields to 2 decimals. E.g. the field [Inventory Reach] . Whenever I add the round function into the query it fails. Could you maybe adjust your CTE example above and add the round function for [Inventory Reach]? Thank you

Comment: You mean `then round([Stock all SP WH]/([calculate 5-year demand]/5), 2)`?

Answer (score 1):

A column alias is not permitted in the `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, or `HAVING` clauses.  You can use a subquery or CTE, but SQL Server supports lateral joins via the `APPLY` keyword.  This can be quite useful for introducing a column alias:

```
select o.Material, o.Plnt, v.[Inventory Reach],
       (case when v.[Inventory Reach] > 9
             then 1
             else 0.9
        end) as [Devaluation Class]
from [BAAS_PowerBI].[dbo].[Obs] o cross apply
     (values (case when o.[calculate 5-year demand] = 0
                   then 9.01
                   when o.[BAAS SO GI (601) 36] = 0
                   then 9.01
                   when o.[MS] in ('BI', 'BO')
                   then (o.[Stock all SP WH] / (o.[calculate 5-year demand] / 5))
                   when o.[MS] = 'BO'
                   then (o.[Stock all SP WH] / o.[BAAS SO GI (601) 36])
                   when o.[MS] ='BI'
                   then 0
                  else 9.01
              end
             )
     ) values([Inventory Reach])
```